# prove that $(x-y)^3+(y-z)^3+(z-x)^3 > 0.$

Tags: inequality

> If $x<y<z$ are real numbers, prove that $$(x-y)^3+(y-z)^3+(z-x)^3 > 0.$$

**Attempt**

We have that $(x-y)^3+(y-z)^3+(z-x)^3=-3 x^2 y+3 x^2 z+3 x y^2-3 x z^2-3 y^2 z+3 y z^2$. Grouping yields $3(x^2z+xy^2+yz^2)-3(x^2y+xz^2+y^2z)$. Then I was thinking of using rearrangement but then I would get $\geq$ instead of $>$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the polynomial
$$S = (x-y)^3 + (y-z)^3 + (z-x)^3$$
is zero whenever two of the variables are equal so we must have
$$S = C(y-x) (z-x) (z-y)$$
for some constant $C$. A direct computation gives $C=3$ and the result follows since all factors are positive when $x < y < z$.

Comment: Nice one ! Simple.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is only the *differences* in the variables that matter, we can subtract the smallest value ($x$) from each term:

$-y^3 + (y-z)^3 + z^3 > 0$.

Let $y = d_1$ and $z-y = d_2$ and note $z = d_1 + d_2$.  Then:

$-d_1^3 - d_2^3 + (d_1 + d_2)^3 > 0$.

Simplify:

$3d_1 d_2^2 + 3 d_1^2 d_2 >0$.

or

$3(d_1 d_2)(d_1 + d_2) > 0$.

Comment: .Since $d_1$ and $d_2$ are positive,  you can stop at the second-last line.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If $a+ b +c=0, a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$

Comment: A monster of a hint.  ;-)) +1 And happy holidays Lab!  - Mark

Comment: @user19405892,  Proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404561/if-a-b-c-in-r-are-distinct-then-a3-b3-c33abc-neq-0

Answer (score 1):

Converting your expression so that all that is cubed is positive:

$$(z-x)^3 - (z-y)^3 - (y-x)^3$$
$$(A+B)^3-A^3-B^3$$

with $A,B$ positive. Since cubing is concave up with $0^3=0$, this expression must be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Hint, $(z-x)^3=\left((z-y)+(y-x)\right)^3$.