# If $\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=\cos A+\cos B+\cos C=0$,

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

> If $$\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=\cos A+\cos B+\cos C=0,$$ prove that
>   $$\cos 3A+\cos 3B+\cos 3C=3\cos(A+B+C).$$

---

My solution:
From the given, 
$$\cos^3A+\cos^3B+\cos^3C=3\cos A\cos B\cos C$$

Now, 
L.H.S$$=\cos3A+\cos3B+\cos3C$$
$$=4\cos^3A-3\cos A+4\cos^3B-3\cos B+4\cos^3C-3\cos C$$
$$=12\cos A \cos B \cos C.$$

My solution ends here. How should I complete?

**NOTE:** I am not allowed to use complex numbers at my level. So, please help me solve this problem without using complex numbers.

Comment: Brute force works: Expand $\cos 3A+\cos 3B+\cos 3C - 3 \cos(A+B+C)$; replace $\sin C$ and $\cos C$ with $-(\sin A+\sin B)$ and $-(\cos A+ \cos B)$, respectively; simplify ... and watch everything magically vanish.

Comment: Here's another insight to help you along. In the step, that is given, write everything as a function of cos(A2). 2Sin^2 A = 1-cos(2A) , 2cos^2(A) = 1 + cos(2A)

Comment: You aren't "allowed" to use complex numbers? Why would your teacher impose that restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have $$sinA+sinB=-sinC$$ and $$cosA+cosB=-cosC$$ squaring and adding both we get

$$2+2cos(A-B)=1$$ that is

$$cos(A-B)=\frac{-1}{2}$$ $\implies$

$$A-B=\frac{2\pi}{3}$$ similarly

$$B-C=\frac{-4\pi}{3}$$ and

$$C-A=\frac{2\pi}{3}$$

Now $$cos3A=cos\left(3\left(B+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right)=cos(3B+2\pi)=cos3B$$

similarly $$cos3C=cos3B$$

Hence

$$cos3A+cos3B+cos3C=3cos3A=3cos(A+A+A)=3cos\left(A+B+\frac{2\pi}{3}+C-\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)=3cos(A+B+C)$$

Comment: This solution was just wonderful, starting with the first step to write sin A + sin B = -sin C

Comment: Give some tips about developing the intuition.

Comment: My only question is that the process is symmetric. So shouldn't, A-B, b-C, C-A be equal ?

Comment: they cannot be equal because when we add them up you have to get zero

Comment: Why should it be zero ?

Comment: $A-B+B-C+C-A=0$

Comment: Good observation

Comment: @user230452, Reminds me of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397066/clarification-regarding-a-question

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma, $$\cos x=\cos A\implies A=2n\pi\pm A$$ where $n$ is any integer.  Why can't $A-B$ be $$-\dfrac{2\pi}3?$$ and why $$B-C$$ has to be $$-\dfrac{4\pi}3$$ ?

Comment: you can take like that only thing we have to make sure is $A-B+B-C+C-A=0$...there are infinite solutions and for any solution we get the final result same.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos (A+B+C)=\cos (A+B) \cos C- \sin (A+B) \sin C \\ = (\cos A \cos B -\sin A \sin B) \cos C -( \sin A \cos B +\cos A \sin B) \sin C \\ =\cos A \cos B \cos C- \sum_{cyc} \sin A \sin B \cos C $

$( \sin A+ \sin B)^2= (-\sin C)^2 , (\cos A +\cos B )^2=(-\cos C)^2  \\ \implies 2+ 2\sin A \sin B +2 \cos A \cos B =1 \\ \implies  \sin A \sin B = -\cos A \cos B -\dfrac{1}{2} \\ \implies \sum_{cyc} \sin A \sin B \cos C =\sum_{cyc} (-\cos A \cos B -\dfrac{1}{2})\cos C  \\ =-3 \cos A \cos B \cos C -\dfrac{1}{2} (\cos A + \cos B + \cos C)=-3 \cos A \cos B \cos C$

Comment: This is rather confusing to read and leaves some parts out, but this answer works out.

Answer (score 1):

Trigonometry is not needed here.

You have three unit vectors with sum $0$, which can only happen if the vectors are the sides of an (oriented) equilateral triangle in some order.  Geometrically this is the statement that one unit circle centered on another unit circle intersects it at points $\pm 60$ degrees from the center of the first circle.

But in that case $A,B,C$ are (in some order) equal to  $\theta, \theta - 120, \theta + 120$ for some angle $\theta$, and we have the stronger result that $3A = 3B = 3C = (A+B+C) = 3\theta$ as angles.  Of course the sines and cosines of those angles will also be equal and this implies the given formula.

Comment: That is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Anyway this is a solution with complex numbers. The solution without the complex numbers can be deduced from here, use the formula $e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)$  and compute the real part at it stage of the following method.

$cos(A)+cos(B)+cos(C)=sin(A)+sin(B)+sin(C)=0$ is equivalent to $e^{iA}+e^{iB}+e^{iC}=0$.

$e^{iA}+e^{iB}+e^{iC}=0$ implies $(e^{iA}+e^{iB}+e^{iC})^3=0$.

We use the identity:

$(a+b+c)^3 = a^3+3a^2b+3a^2c+3ab^2+6abc+3ac^2+b^3+3b^2c+3bc^2+c^3$

Thus we have:

$e^{3iA}+ 3e^{2iA}e^{iB}+3e^{2iA}e^{iC}+3e^{iA}e^{2iB}+6e^{i(A+B+C)}+3e^{iA}e^{2iC}+e^{3iB}+3e^{2iB}e^{iC}+3e^{iB}e^{2iC}=0$

$=e^{3iA}+e^{3iB}+e^{3iC}+3e^{iA}e^{iB}(e^{iA}+e^{iB})+3e^{iA}e^{iC}(e^{iA}+e^{iC})+3e^{iB}e^{iC}(e^{iB}+e^{iC})+6e^{i(A+B+C)}=0$

We use here $e^{iA}+e^{iB}+e^{iC}=0$ which implies $e^{iA}e^{iB}(e^{iA}+e^{iB})=-e^{iA}e^{iB}e^{iC}$.

We deduce

$e^{3iA}+e^{3iB}+e^{3iC} -3e^{iA}e^{iB}e^{iC}-3e^{iA}e^{iB}e^{iC}-3e^{iA}e^{iB}e^{iC}+6e^{i(A+B+C)}=0$.

$e^{3iA}+e^{3iB}+e^{3iC} = 3(e^{iA}+e^{iB}+e^{iC})$

thus $cos(3A)+cos(3B)+cos(3C)=3(cos(A)+cos(B)+cos(C))$.

Comment: "NOTE: I am not allowed to use complex numbers at my level. So, please help me solve this problem without using complex numbers."

Comment: @Tsemo, An easier proof : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404561/if-a-b-c-in-r-are-distinct-then-a3-b3-c33abc-neq-0