# How to factorize the polynomial $a^6+8a^3+27$?

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

> I would like to factorize $a^6+8a^3+27$.

I got different answers but one of the answers is

$$(a^2-a+3)(a^4+a^3-2a^2+3a+9)$$

Can someone tell me how to get this answer? Thanks.

Comment: You can write $b=a^3$ so it becomes $b^2+8b+27$ which you can factor as a quadratic.  Then substitute $a^3$ back in and see if you can factor either of those cubics.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, $b^2+8b+27=(b+4+\sqrt{-11})(b+4-\sqrt{-11})$.  How does that help?

Comment: @BarryCipra it helps because you've now got two cubics instead of one sixth degree.  In fact an easy cubic because it is of the form $a^3+c$, the roots are $\sqrt[3]{c}$ times the three possible roots of unity.  So yes that gets you all the way there to six linear factors.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, I'd really like to see how you get from those six linear factors back to a factorization over the integers.

Comment: @BarryCipra Easy, two factors will be complex conjucates of each other, multiply those together, then multiply together the other four.  That will give you alternate factorizations including the one above.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, I'd still like to see the *details* of this approach.  After all, what you've described works just as easily for finding a factorization of $a^6+8a^3+26$....

Answer (score 3):

$$a^6+8a^3+27= (a^2)^3+3^3+(-a)^3-3\cdot a^2\cdot3(-a)$$

Now $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$$

**See** :  [If $a,b,c \in R$ are distinct, then $-a^3-b^3-c^3+3abc \neq 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404561/if-a-b-c-in-r-are-distinct-then-a3-b3-c33abc-neq-0)

Comment: A good connection to find!

Answer (score 3):

The roots of $a^6+8a^3+27$ are the cubic roots of the roots of $x^2+8x+27$,
 given by $-4\pm\sqrt{-11}$. If we set $\alpha=-4+\sqrt{-11}=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{-11}}{2}\right)^3$ and $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$,
 it follows that:

$$ a^6+8a^3+27 = \color{red}{\left(a-\alpha^{1/3}\right)\left(a-\bar{\alpha}^{1/3}\right)}\color{blue}{\left(a-\omega\alpha^{1/3}\right)\left(a-\omega\bar{\alpha}^{1/3}\right)\left(a-\omega^2\alpha^{1/3}\right)\left(a-\omega^2\bar{\alpha}^{1/3}\right)}$$
and we just have to understand how to "couple back" such factors (as suggested by colors),
 that is easy through the identities
$$ \alpha^{1/3}+\bar{\alpha}^{1/3}=1,\qquad \alpha\bar{\alpha}=3^3,\qquad \omega+\bar{\omega}=-1. $$

Comment: I must be having another off day, because I don't see how you got the first identity, nor how the identities help pick out which pair of complex conjugates give the quadratic factor $a^2-a+3$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: there was a miscomputation on my side, but I hope everything is easier to follow now.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  So the secret is recognizing $-4+\sqrt{-11}$ as a cube of something nice.

Answer (score 2):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
a^6+8a^3+27&=a^3\left(a^3+\frac{27}{a^3}+8 \right)
\\&=a^3\left(\left(a+\frac3a\right)^3-9\left(a+\frac3a\right)+9-1 \right)
\\&=a^3\left(\left[\left(a+\frac3a\right)^3-1\right]-9\left[\left(a+\frac3a\right)-1\right] \right)
\\&=a^3\left(a+\frac3a-1\right)\left(\left(a+\frac3a\right)^2+\left(a+\frac3a\right)-8 \right)
\\&=a \cdot \left(a+\frac3a-1\right)\cdot a^2 \cdot\left(\left(a+\frac3a\right)^2+\left(a+\frac3a\right)-8 \right)
\\&=\left(a^2-a+3\right)(a^4+a^3-2a^2+3a+9).
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly sneaky way to arrive at the factorization.

Let $P(a)=a^6+8a^3+27$.  Then

$$P(10)=1008027=3\cdot3\cdot31\cdot3613=93\cdot3\cdot3613=(10^2-10+3)\cdot3\cdot3613$$

so we might *guess* that $a^2-a+3$ is a factor of $a^6+8a^3+27$.  If it is, then the other factor would have to take the form $a^4+a^3+\cdots+9$ (so that the product with $a^2-a+3$ has no $a^5$ term and ends with a $27$), and we can see that

$$3\cdot3613=10839=10^4+10^3-2\cdot10^2+3\cdot10+9$$

suggests $a^4+a^3-2a^2+3a+9$ as the other factor.

Note, one might also try grouping $P(10)=9\cdot31\cdot3613=(10-1)\cdot31\cdot3613$, but $a-1$ is clearly not a factor.  (Note also that the hard work that's been swept under the rug here is the work that goes into factoring $1008027$.)

Answer (score 0):

By the [rational root theorem](http://www.sparknotes.com/math/algebra2/polynomials/section4.rhtml), we guess the factors include at least one of the following:

$$x \pm 27$$

$$x \pm 9$$

$$x \pm 3$$

$$x \pm 1$$

Where did I get those?

1. Take the absolute value of the last term (in descending order), $27$, and the absolute value of the last term, $1$.
2. Take the factors of each:

$$27: \color{red}{1,3,9,27}$$

$$1: \color{green}{1}$$

3. Consider $x-a$ where $a$ may be any of the ff:

$$\pm \frac{\color{red}{27}}{\color{green}{1}}$$

$$\pm \frac{\color{red}{9}}{\color{green}{1}}$$

$$\pm \frac{\color{red}{3}}{\color{green}{1}}$$

$$\pm \frac{\color{red}{1}}{\color{green}{1}}$$